# Product of zero sets is a zero sets

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

I'm writing a proof about the cross product of zero sets $A\subset\mathbb{R}^a$ and $B\subset\mathbb{R}^b$ being a zero set, i.e. that $A\times B\subset\mathbb{R}^{a+b}$ is a zero set. This is my attempt:

Since $A,B$ are zero sets, we know that both of them have covers by open rectangles, say $O_i$ and $U_j$ respectively. Hence that for $\varepsilon_1,\varepsilon_2>0$ we have $\sum_{i}|O_i|<\varepsilon_1$ and $\sum_{j}|U_j|<\varepsilon_2$. Now note that it suffices to show that $A\times\mathbb{R}^b$ is a zero set. So let us proceed by induction on $b$ to prove this.

For the base case $b=1$, notice that $A\times\mathbb{R}=\cup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}A\times[-n,n]$, so we can cover each of the parts of the union by $\sum_{i}|O_i|2n$, as the length of $[-n,n]$ is $2n$. Then $\sum_{i}|O_i|2n<\varepsilon_12n$, so if we let $\varepsilon_1=\frac{\varepsilon}{2n}$, we get  $\sum_{i}|O_i|2n<\varepsilon$ for all $\varepsilon>0$.

As for the inductive step, let $A'=A\times\mathbb{R}^b$. Then applying the base case to $A'\times\mathbb{R}$ gives the wanted result.

Hence finally, $A\times\mathbb{R}^b$ is a zero set and then so is $A\times B$.

Does this work?

Thanks for any answers!

Comment: Since $A\times B\subset\mathbb A\times \mathbb R^b$ you have that $m(A\times B)\leq m(A\times\mathbb R^b)=0$ so yes it works

Comment: Also if $A\subset\mathbb R^a$ and $B\subset\mathbb R^b$ you have $m_{a+b}(A\times B)=m_a(A)m_b(B)$ where $m_i$ is the lebesgue measure for $\mathbb R^i$